# Complex number $\tan \alpha+i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Given that $z=\tan \alpha+i$, where $0<\alpha<\frac{1}{2}\pi$

Find $\left |z  \right |$.

I've never seen this kind of example in my book. Can anyone guide me? Thanks a lot.

How to find $arg z$ then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the modulus, using 
$$|z| = \sqrt{[\mathrm{Re}(z)]^2+[\mathrm{Im}(z)]^2}$$
we have
\begin{align*}
|z| &= \sqrt{\tan^2 \alpha + 1^1}\\
&= \sqrt{\sec^2 \alpha}\\
&= |\sec \alpha|\\
&= \sec \alpha, \quad \mbox{for} \quad 0 < \alpha < \frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{align*}
And for the argument, using
$$\arg (z) = \tan^{-1} \left (\frac{\mathrm{Im}(z)}{\mathrm{Re}(z)} \right )$$
we have
\begin{align*}
\arg (z) &= \tan^{-1} \left (\frac{1}{\tan \alpha} \right )\\
&= \tan^{-1} (\cot \alpha)\\
&= \tan^{-1} (\tan(\pi/2 - \alpha))\\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha, \quad \mbox{for} \quad 0 < \alpha < \frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: The answer given is $\pi/2-\alpha.$

Comment: Small mistake. Have now corrected my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.

$1^2+(\tan \alpha)^2=(\sec \alpha)^2$

So $\left |z  \right |=\sec \alpha$

Is it right?

Comment: Sounds good. Where did you use that $0<\alpha<\frac{\pi}{2}$? Small consideration.

Comment: ^The restriction $0 < \alpha < \pi/2$ is not needed to get $|z| = \sec \alpha$, but it will be useful to find $\arg z$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 how to get $\arg z$?

Answer (score 2):

just plot the complex number $z = \tan \alpha  + i$ in the gauss plane. $z$ makes an angle $\alpha$ with the positive $y$-axis and $\pi/2 - \alpha$ with the positive $x$-axis which is the argument of $z.$ from the right angle triangle, you get the hypotenuse $|z| = \frac1{\cos \alpha}.$  therefore the polar representation of $z$ is $$z = \frac1{\cos \alpha}e^{i(\pi/2 - \alpha)}. $$